# sensitivity of ultrasound transducer related to output

Tags: ultrasound, sensitivity

Can any one explain to me how is the sensitivity of an uktrasound head related to the Output pressure Level?

Comment: for example i am using an ultrasound head with sensitivity -87dB, I want to know how an increase in Input voltage affects the Output pressure, or pressure Level?

Comment: for example in the data sheet I have: For 10Vrms, SPL =103dB at30 cm. I want to know how much SPL I get if the Voltage =80Vrms. can you help me?

Comment: Let's spell this out. You mention a sensitivity level of -87 dB and that relates to using the head as a receiver but you go on to mention raising the input voltage to increase the output pressure. That does not make sense. If you truly want an answer that is useful you need to make clearer statements and provide a link to the device's data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a transducer with a rated SPL of 103dB(*something*) at 10V rms input, and drive it with 80Vrms, what SPL would you get out?

You may hope that the output will increase in linear ratio to the input. That is for an 8 times voltage input increase, the SPL would increase by 8 times, or \$20log_{10}(8) = 18dB\$ for 121dB(*something*) output.

However, 8 times is a lot of increase. If I was presenting a part for sale, that was capable of that output, would I list its performance at 1/8th of the pressure, 1/64th of its possible output power? Here's a Ferrari, it will do 20mph? I think not. I think if it were capable of 121dB(*something*) SPL, then it would be rated at 80Vrms input. I suspect it will fall apart long before it reaches that.

But it might hold together, you might be lucky.